# c# eventArgs form events

Tags: c#, events, types, custom-events

I have multiple form with the same design like:

```
In Form1{
Form2 = new Formtoopen();
Form2.Resize += new EventHandler(Form2_Resize);
Form2.FormClosing +=new FormClosingEventHandler(Form2_FormClosing);
}
```

and then the events:

```
In Form1{
protected virtual void Fly_Form2_Closing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing)
   {
      e.Cancel = true;
      Fly_Form2.Hide();
   }
}

protected virtual void Fly_Form2_Visiblechanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //some code
}
}
```

I would like to add the Form2 Type in the EventArgs that is empty from now.
I think it would make my code simpler as I have multiple Form sharing the same code.

How could I do that? I thought about the event custom arguments way but i'm not sure with Type...

Could you help me?

Thanks

Comment: Why would you want to include the type in there. As the event is triggerd by the form itself doing `this.Hide()` should do what you want. Or rather since the form is the sender cast it to the form type and then hide it.

Comment: Hello, 'Cause when I do This.Hide it's hiding the Form1 behind my Form2. The code is in Form1 and I open all my forms from that and dealing with them from Form1. so I'm in Form1 when I call the this.Hide and it's hiding Form1 and not the form I'm seeing....

Comment: It is handed to you on a silver platter: ((Form)sender).Hide();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is something that works:

```
 In Form1{
Form2 = new Formtoopen();
Form3 = new Formdata();
Form2.FormClosing +=new FormClosingEventHandler(Form_FormClosing);
Form3.FormClosing += new FormClosingEventHandler(Form_FormClosing);
}

 In Form1{
protected virtual void Form_Closing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs  e)
{
if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing)
{
  e.Cancel = true;
  ((Form)sender).Hide();
}
}
```

Retrieving the sender with cast Form from the object sender.

Thanks a lot M.Passant!